# JavaScript .select() not working with Webforms in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, webforms

I'm want to copy text from a webpage to the clipboard using JavaScript, however .select() is not working in Chrome (version 63).

Code is as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function preventDefault(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        var copyText = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtClientDetailsName");
        copyText.select();
        document.execCommand("Copy");

        return false;
    }
</script>

<p id="nameTag">Name: </p>
<asp:Label ID="lblClientDetailsName" runat="server" autopostback="false"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtClientDetailsName" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Enabled="false">Testing</asp:TextBox>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCopyTitle" runat="server" OnClientClick="preventDefault(event)" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span>
</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Content>
```

I've tried it in Edge and it's working perfectly.  Searches online have suggested calling copyText.focus(), however this doesn't work either.

The code is essentially a copy of the w3schools guide at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp which works fine on Chrome.

Comment: Cant see any input fields with ID `MainContent_txtClientDetailsName`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kumar.  It comes from the Content (added to example) - I can see that it's appended to the start of `txtClientDetailsName` when I view my source.

Comment: prevent the mouseup event to keep the selection

Comment: Does your view have a input type with  ID `MainContent_txtClientDetailsName` ?

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas Yep, I have `<input name="ctl00$MainContent$txtClientDetailsName" type="text" value="Testing" readonly="readonly" id="MainContent_txtClientDetailsName" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine the issue is you are disabling textbox when you disable textbox in webform  `copyText.select();` is not working 
remove these attributes `ReadOnly="true" Enabled="false"` it's working fine with existing code if you do not want to remove these attributes then use below js method it's work for you.

```
<script>
function preventDefault(event) {
    var copyText = document.getElementById("<%=txtClientDetailsName.ClientID%>");
    $(copyText).removeAttr('ReadOnly Enabled disabled')
    $(copyText).removeClass('aspNetDisabled')

  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
  $(copyText).attr({
      ReadOnly:"true",
      disabled:"disabled",
  })
  $(copyText).addClass('aspNetDisabled')
  event.preventDefault();
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this Hafiz, your suggestion worked perfectly.  I narrowed the problem down to the `Enabled="false"` attribute specifically and gone down your suggested route of temporarily removing the attribute through the code.

Answer (score 0):

In chrome we have this known issue, We have to disable the onmouseup  event to keep the selection.

```
function preventDefault(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  var copyText = document.getElementById("MainContent_txtClientDetailsName");
  copyText.onmouseup = function(){return false};
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Rahul, unfortunately it behaves the same after preventing the onmouseup event.

Comment: It may be due to browser cache.. please check the view source , if the javascript updated or not

Comment: To test the you may open https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page in chrome, in console please run the code

document.getElementById("p-logo").onclick =function(event)
{
  event.preventDefault();
  var copyText = document.getElementById("searchInput");
  copyText.onmouseup = function(){return false};
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
}

and when ever you click on the logo, you will find the search box is selected

Comment: JavaScript is definitely updated, checked in source.  I've just tried the above test you suggested, however this also does not update my clipboard.

Comment: Please write some thing in the search box then only it will be copied, the default text is a place holder only